# HttpRequestMessage.Content comes with invalid and unreadable characters

Tags: c#, json, .net, http, xamarin

When I get the return from HttpRequestMessage.Contenc it comes as if it was encrypted. someone already went through something similar

```
        var client2 = new HttpClient();

        client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = uri,
            Headers = {
            { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), $"Bearer {resulttoken.access_token}" },
            },
            Content = new StringContent(dic.ToString())
        };

        //posting the data here to the endpoint and capturing the request.
        var response_teste = client2.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
        var Result_final = await response_teste.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Result /

"�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�M�0@\u1ad0���c��p�\a(��6A��aa�w��{_F��ld/�RG!(��y^��E�Y�18mԩb�����{�\fk%����ԭ��BsCH��זU�U6Z��z���{);�]4�a\n�+�~�4*�`����0�1N-tR��/����\0\0\0"

Comment: Revolvido             HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            });

Comment: What Josias wrote here + Jiang's answer fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` directly, you could use `response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync()` as follows to check whether it works:

```
var buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
var byteArray = buffer.ToArray();
var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

This is working in my case and I guess that using UTF8 should solve most of the issues.